# How do you know what port to use for a static IP (as a proxy)?

Tags: port, ip-address, static-ip

Does the static IP provider specify it, or is it an arbitrary number you pick from a range?

For instance, where the proxy format would be: `https://username:password@static_IP_address:portNumber`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is closer to "a number you pick from a range".

TCP works by having, among other fields a source and destination IP address and source and destination port.  These 4 things are required for a unique session.

The port is a 2 byte number, so between 0 and 65535.  Services are commonly associated with default ports, but these are typically just by convention.   There is 1 bit which, depending on your OS may not be - on some OS's ports below 1024 are only accessible by the superuser account.

It is, of-course, the server that defines the port here.

Comment: Could you advise me on (or confirm) the following? I'm hoping to narrow down what information I should request from a client paying for this static IP. Along with the static IP address, I assume I should ask for the username/password, http type (http or https), and the port number. I want to be confident that I ask for nothing unneeded.

Comment: Your question in the comment does not follow. What service are you providing this client?

Comment: To clarify, he's not paying me for the static IP. He's my client in a related capacity, the point being I want to be sure not to confuse him. He needs to send me a paid proxy IP address I will use in an application I built for him (if that helps to know).

Comment: Where does the proxy address come into this? Also, why is an http proxy being used?

Comment: I appreciate your time here - The answer I'm looking for may be simpler than it appears. He ordered a static IP from a VPN service and needs to give me the details so I can utilize it (as a whitelisted proxy address) for him. He might think that he only needs to send me the IP address - I know he needs to send me more info, but I don't want to ask for something that isn't provided by that VPN service (that I should figure out myself, like the port number). Based on your response, I won't ask him for the http type - I'll ask for the username/password and, of course, IP address.

Comment: p2 That said, my question is: Should I _also_ ask him for a port number/range (I'm still not sure whether his VPN service would provide that number/range)?

Comment: It is still very unclear to me why you need anything more then his static IP.  Also, you were talking about a proxy but now a VPN?????

Comment: The static IP is purchased from a VPN service, which was necessary to mention as the question relates to whether the VPN service would provide the port number/range specifics. The following, I'm sure, is needed in addition to his static IP: credentials. What I'm not sure of, and the question remains: 'Would the VPN service specify the port number/range I should use also (if a port number is needed in this case).' If you don't know the answer, it's certainly no blemish to your expertise in this field. If there is no answer, I'll plan to only ask him for the credentials initially.

Comment: I don't understand why you need anything more then the static IP address of his VPN.  I still don't understand where a proxy comes into it.   As to port ranges the VPN provider does not assign port ranges, it assigns an IP address.  Ports are a property associated with an IP address [ for a TCP connection] and are determined by his computer and your server.

Comment: Oh, okay. I think that helps. I apologize if at all myopic in my use of the lingo. In the area of coding, using specific IP addresses are labeled as "proxies" (as the purpose there is to route traffic through to that IP address, instead of the one used by the computer running the script), such as `'proxy': 'https://username:password@IPaddress:port_number'` -- Although credentials (and perhaps ports) aren't always needed in this use. Unless I'm incorrect in my understanding of how to use the static IP address, we may just be using different labels regarding proxies.

Comment: Apologies, but you don't appear to grasp the basics of internet connectivity and I doubt anyone can help you unless you provide more information on what you are doing.  If you are simply wanting to only allow traffic from him through his static IP address you don't use a proxy.  Even in a coding sense, IP addresses are not proxies - a proxy uses an IP address and other resources, but that is not something you would require of your client.  If indeed a proxy is applicable - and I don't think it is - you would be the one providing the details of your proxy server for him to enter.

Comment: p1: You've made a few assumptions, which is why this would have been considerably quicker (that you didn't have a precise answer) if you would have answered what I originally asked to the best of your ability (again, no knock on your expertise). 1. I'm not allowing traffic 'from him,' (nor did I imply that) 2. I didn't say nor think IP addresses are proxies (and to be clear, in a coding sense, proxies are widely considered to be used as I described) [See p4]. Third, to know whether I required those details of my client (who is a person, if that wasn't clear by now), you would need to...

Comment: p2: ...know the purpose and details of the application - which, to be clear, was not required to know to answer the question. The question pattern I noticed from you is apropos to a relatively common want of details that piqued one’s interest, and would make a conversation more interesting, no doubt, but will tend to circumnavigate the problem at hand (possibly in effort to avoid having the wrong answer or no answer at all, but I reserve judgment).

Comment: p3 - ...other than that, apology accepted

Comment: p4: for more information on the use of an 'HTTP proxy' with a static IP in coding, see the bullet point 'Using an HTTP Proxy' at help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticIPForExternalWhitelists, as one example - Again, proxy is a common shorthand in the area of coding; Especially within the bounds of code itself, it's sensical to label the effective 'proxy' process (which includes the IP address) as 'proxy,' which is why it's commonplace

Comment: I read your link in "p4".  I understand **exactly*" what a proxy is, and the usage in that link is exactly consistent with my understanding.  Your comment is confused and nonsensical where it is not factually incorrect. There is no point in trying to further help you unless you explain exactly where a proxy fits into your connectivity requirements, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I'll let it slide, but yes, again you effectively 'ad hominem by calling non-sense [1]’. What you haven’t yet gleaned, is there is nothing further I need here, especially in that you appear to bring some toxicity to the discussion. But no harm, no foul. Thanks anyway; You were a help, albeit unexpectedly minor. Again, not a knock - It’s okay not to have a “perfect” answer, as frequently there isn’t one (which includes this case). “…basics of internet connectivity” :-D. Take care/off. This thread is dead (post further in solitude).

Comment: [1] - in the sense that nothing has been rebutted on your end yet (you didn’t specify where I was wrong in my original and subsequent explanations).